# Округление числа js

Tags: javascript, округление

У меня есть число, к примеру, 3833383. Пробовал `Math.round()`, но ведь это целое число. Как мне его округлить до 4 миллиoнов?

Comment: `round(num/1000000)*1000000`.

Comment: @Grundy Вы не правы. В дубликате указаны решение округления дробной части. А здесь нужно округлить целую. А `num.toFixed(-6)` вызывает ошибку

Comment: @AntonShchyrov, добавил еще один источник.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```js
console.log(Math.round(3833383 / 1e6) * 1e6);
```